# Desired output using awk command

Tags: bash, awk

Below is my requirement.

My input file (test.csv):

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a b c d
e f g h
.
.
```

Expected output:

```
col1:a
col2:b
col3:c
col4:d
col1:e
col2:f
col3:g
col4:h
.
.
```

I don't have much experience on awk programming, used below code. But results are not as expected. can someone help on this.

```
awk { for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print $i ":"} test.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{if(NR==1){ split($0, a) }else{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i]":"$i }}' test.csv
```

The output:

```
col1:a
col2:b
col3:c
col4:d
col1:e
col2:f
col3:g
col4:h
```

---

`NR==1` - for the first record

`split($0, a)` - split the first record into an array of column names, so that `a[1]` is assigned with `col1`, `a[2]` is filled with `col2` and so on ...

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i]":"$i` - prints column name and column value basing on respective index `i`

Comment: Getting `awk: 0602-553 Function split is not defined` error. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: @NaveenReddyCH, what's your awk version? Show `awk -V | head -n1`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest They will be on AIX with that error. Although I just checked now and split is a function on AIX, so dunno actually.

Comment: Yes server is AIX only. `awk -V` is giving me `Not a recognized flag` error.

Comment: Sorry its my bad, I have given it as `spilt`. Thanks for your help. This is working fine for me now :)

Comment: @NaveenReddyCH, yes, "spilt" is not "split" ))

Comment: haha yes..it looks like it is not treating blanks properly. if I don't have field it is assigning next value not the blank

Comment: @NaveenReddyCH, you should have mentioned that in your question (that there could be empty fields)

Comment: If there are blanks in the file, like: `a  c d` (instead of `b` there is empty which doesn't show here) define `FS` to single space: `-F"[ ]"` and it outputs relevant line: `col2:`

Comment: @JamesBrown, I know that technique. I just wanted to make all in proper way: "clear question" - "full answer"

Comment: Yes I should have asked in question..I got this scenario after posting the question. Anyway thanks for your help :)